# lapply over nested list and retain naming/structure

Tags: r

When creating nested lists R has, what I consider, helpful naming structure for the elements of the list.  I have a list of lists and want to apply a function of every single vector contained within any list.  `lapply` does this but then strips the naming structure of the list.  How can I `lapply` of every vector element of the nested list without stripping the names?  I tried passing the index instead but that seems to do the same thing (strip names).

```
TEST <- list(n1=list(a="5", b="65"), n2=list(a="f", b= "f6"))
TEST
lapply(TEST, function(x) gsub("6", "foo", x))
lapply(seq_along(TEST), function(i) gsub("6", "foo", TEST[[i]]))
```

Console Output:

```
> TEST
$n1
$n1$a
[1] "5"

$n1$b
[1] "65"


$n2
$n2$a
[1] "f"

$n2$b
[1] "f6"


> lapply(TEST, function(x) gsub("6", "foo", x))
$n1
[1] "5"    "foo5"

$n2
[1] "f"    "ffoo"
```

Desired outcome:

```
$n1
$n1$a
[1] "5"

$n1$b
[1] "foo5"


$n2
$n2$a
[1] "f"

$n2$b
[1] "ffoo"
```

Comment: @shujaa yes I edited to reflect your comment

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems you want the `rapply` variant of the *apply family

```
rapply(TEST, function(x){gsub("6", "foo", x)}, how = "list")

$n1
$n1$a
[1] "5"

$n1$b
[1] "foo5"


$n2
$n2$a
[1] "f"

$n2$b
[1] "ffoo"
```

You could also do it like this to avoid writing an anonymous function

```
rapply(TEST, gsub, pattern = "6", replacement = "foo", how = "list")
```

Comment: Ohh new R voodoo magic I've never played with.  Thanks Dason.  I knew about `rapply` but not how or why to use it.  Perfect.

Comment: Any other way without `rapply`? it evaluates its arguments so it is not useful when looping over language objects.

Comment: @JanGorecki Sounds like you should open a new question